# Видимость переменных PHP

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой и не очень понимаю, почему так происходит.

у меня есть такая ситуация:

```
get_template('templates/home/static.php');

function get_template($path) {
  require_once($path);
}
```

и такое:

```
get_header();

function get_header($title = NULL, $description = NULL, $keywords = NULL) {
  require_once('templates/header.php');
  get_nav();
}
```

Эти функции вызываются в одном файле **home.php** и выглядит эта картина так:

```
<?php
  get_header();
  get_template('templates/home/static.php');
  get_footer();?>
```

Вопрос заключается вот в чем: в файле **header.php** есть переменные, которые нужны в **static.php**, но когда я реализую это через функции - переменные недоступны. Но стоит мне убрать "красивый вид использования функций" и оставить чистый **require**, то всё работает.

Почему так происходит? Я разве использую функции не для простой вставки содержимого файла **header.php** и **static.php** в **home.php**? Возможно ли реализовать как-то добавление файлов с сохранением содержимых переменных через функции? Или остается только использовать костыль в виде добавления файла, в который добавляются другие файлы?

Comment: "Почему так происходит? " --- потому что include и require  внутри функции вставляют данные внутрь функции ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   . Было бы странно если функция, которая ограничивает область видимости позволяла бы выглядывать переменным наружу....и не важно require там и или что-то ещё

Comment: "в файле header.php есть переменные, которые нужны в static.php," --- какие и зачем?  разве это не должно быть всё независимо?

Comment: очень странная конструкция, это вообще легально `once` внутри функции?

Comment: @DaniilLoban а почему нет? например во фреймворках перевод данных из урл в нужный вызов контроллера так примерно и делается

Comment: @АлексейШиманский т.е. если просто `require`  написать будет разница?

Comment: @DaniilLoban  в некоторых случаях вполне очень даже

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вопрос видимо в том, что require_once при повторном вызове ничего не выполнит и вернёт 1. Что делает функцию немного недетерменированной

Comment: @Илья недевно давал ответ на похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1437763/php-mvc-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%91%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-views/1437793#1437793). Посмотрите, может быть будет полезно.